# Descending Order By Month SQL when date type is varchar using C# csharp

Tags: c#, sql

I have a column where date format is `MM/yyyy` stored in a varchar data type. Now I want to order it descending by `MM/yyyy`. How it is possible...
I have tried converted, str_date but failed...

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store dates as strings.  If you have to for some reason, then use YYYYMM format, so they can be ordered.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: See, this is the problem you get when storing dates as strings. My basic recommendation would be to convert the db data so it is properly stored as dates, then this won't happen, and you can do other wonderful things with the data. Like math

Comment: Actually I want Store only Month and year in DATABASE thats why i set DATAType varchar otherwise in date datatype it give error, now another problem occurred that i posted... Thankx for your comment

Comment: @WaqarCH, even if you just want the year and month, you should use a `DATE` and just ignore the day (or always use 1).  The moment you want to do a meaningful time-based SQL query on it, your strings are going to fall over again.

Answer (score 3):

You can use string functions for the ordering.  Most databases support `left()` and `right()`:

```
order by right(mmyyyy, 4), left(mmyyyy, 2)
```

However, you should fix your data model so the value is stored as a *bona fide* date, say the first day of the month.